# Broken index.php after changing server root / directory in WAMP Server

Tags: php, wamp, httpd.conf

This was my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www"
  <Directory "C:/wamp64/www">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Since I travel a lot and use different systems/laptops while traveling, I will like to save and develop my projects from OneDrive/Cloud so that I can work on my projects at anytime from any system.

So I make the server and www directories in my OneDrive and changed the Server Directory to

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/user/OneDrive/server/www"
<Directory "C:/Users/user/OneDrive/server/www/">
```

After copying a project in OneDrive, I am getting following error whenever I load localhost in my browser:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/Users/user/OneDrive/server/www/project/index.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

If I change back the server directory to previous location of www directory, i.e. `"c:/wamp64/www"` the error is gone. Seems this error pops up for every other www location rather than the installation directory. Any help will be grateful.

Thanks

**EDIT**

It's not for just index.php, it's for any file. No file is able to load and same error is being popped-out. Even if the file contains not a single line of code.

Comment: Kind of broad. However I would suggest looking to how you do path traversal for all your include/require calls. Make it self-defining, using `__DIR__` and the like to have it look for files regardless what directory structure it lives in or serves from.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, please check the edit part, it's not just for index.php, but for any file. Even the file contains no code

Comment: Oh. Well then, that changes matters :-) Do you have an htaccess in the project dir?

Comment: @IncredibleHat, Yes and No. Some projects have, some not

Comment: Sorry, I'm pulling a blank here as well with the provided information. Something, somewhere (clearly not inside the .php files themselves if even an EMPTY .php does it), is trying to load `project/index.php` when you go to the site. It puts that at the end of the host directory, and doesn't find it when you change from `C:/wamp64/www/`. Other than an htaccess, I'm unsure where or why it would be doing that. Sorry :(

Comment: It's a permission issue no? Looked at `auto_prepend_file`? Will it load index.html? Error is confusing. Scale back till it works.